# Can Settings.Secure.Android_ID be null?

Tags: android, android-identifiers

I'm looking to use `Settings.Secure.Android_ID` in my app. However I was wondering if it could ever be `null`. According to one of the answers on the topic in 2010 it could be `null` ([Is there a unique Android device ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785485/is-there-a-unique-android-device-id)). However the Android official doc does not mention anything about its nullability.

I was wondering if anyone has used it and can clarify this?

Thanks

Comment: if you use an emulator, its return null/empty value for this system property. an old doc here -> https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html

Answer (score 0):

It happens very rarely but yes it happens on Blackview devices.
I can see `NullPointerException` in crashlytics for this brand only for this setting.